# How to add a specific day of the week when asking about opening & closing time

Tags: grammar

I know it's very basic but I am a beginner... If anybody could be of any help it would be fantastic :)

I know how to ask about closing and opening time (of shops, offices etc) but I don't know how to answer if for example the closing and opening time is different during weekend or on a specific day.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: So, you want to answer with something like:
On weekdays, we are open 9 to 7, and on weekends 12-9?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply preface the specific days with `<day(s)> は`. Ex.

> - [本店]{ほん・てん}の[営業時間]{えい・ぎょう・じ・かん}は9:00から20:00までです。　→　This store's business hours are from 9:00 to 20:00.
> - 金曜日は  <another schedule>　→　A specific day
> - [平日]{へい・じつ}は <another schedule>　→　Weekdays
> - [週末]{しゅう・まつ}・[土日]{ど・にち}は  <another schedule>　→　Weekends/Sat. & Sun.
> - [月火水]{げつ・か・すい}は  <another schedule>　→　Multiple days (here, Mon., Tues., and Wed.)
> - [祝日]{しゅく・じつ}は  <another schedule>　→　Holidays